# Having problems with input using Code::Blocks

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am using Code::Blocks as IDE. I typed the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int x = 1;
    int number;

    while (x <= 5)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> number;
        x++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `cin >> number;` doesn't seem to work i.e the console box appears but I can't input any values.

All I know is that according to the code that I've written above, I'm supposed to type 5 numbers on the blank black box or screen (is it called the console box or application) until the box displays something like this:

> process returned 0 <0x0> execution time : 5.59 s press any key to
>   continue

All I see is the black screen appearing and displaying something like:

> process returned 1542<9845x35452>  execution time 1.12 s press any key
>   to continue

Even before I have typed any numbers.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: If you have a project, make sure it's a console application. By the way, it's a console window and CodeBlocks is an IDE, not a compiler. You're probably using GCC as a compiler.

Comment: it is a console application and yes i think i am using a GCC compiler. well the cout<< seems to be working perfectly but there seems to be a problem with the cin<<.  someone told me there's a problem with the main diagnosis. i don't know what that means . Please help